# Green Box in Profiles

Tags: profile

I want to remove these green boxes that appear on Civi Profiles automatically. They do not appear in the source code at all. Is there an option to remove or a place in Civi where I can disable and change the appearance of these boxes?

[image]

Comment: Can you add more information? What CMS are you using? Include more in your screenshot and/or add information of what url or locations are showing the green box.

Answer (score 3):

These boxes are intended to hold the "Pre-form help".  If you go to **Administer menu » Customize Data and Screens » Profiles**, and click **Settings** next to the affected profile, you'll see the *Pre-form help* option I'm referencing.

One of the following is happening:

- There's some white space in the box.  Do a "Select All" on the text of the box and press Delete, and save.  See if it's fixed.  You can use the **Preview** option under the **More** menu on the Profiles screen.
- If it is NOT fixed, there may be something that's adding space into that box inadvertently.  This happened in CiviCRM about 10 years ago, and occasionally happens because of some odd WordPress plugin or similar.  If you know how to look at the raw database data, look in the (unintuitively-named) table `civicrm_uf_group` at the `help_pre` field.  It should be `NULL`.